# Add tags to RSS title/preview

Tags: feature-request, tags, title, feed

In [a recent Stack Exchange podcast](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/05/podcast-47-do-you-even-twitter-bro/), the point was made that titles sometimes don't stand on their own and need tags to give them context. Joel asked "is there anywhere we show the title but not the tags?" and the answer is yes: **in the RSS feed, tags are not shown, and titles alone can be confusing due to this lack of context.**

I would like the most popular tag to be added to the RSS item title in the same way it's added to the web page title, but simply adding all the tags at the top of the item body is another possible solution.

Comment: Actually, tags are present; from an Atom feed containing this very post: `<category scheme="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tags" term="feature-request"/><category scheme="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tags" term="tags"/><category scheme="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tags" term="title"/><category scheme="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tags" term="rss"/>`. Of course, one can argue that this is inadequate since not all feed consumers keep this information. I just want to make sure the facts are known to start with.

Comment: @Kevin so they are, but they are not visible in Google Reader, feedly or Yoleo.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the top tag to the title makes sense, since that's how questions are displayed in search results and in the title bar of the browser, etc.